# Vue.js 2 : Evaluating async html content (from markdown) with custom directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

It's been a couple of days i'm trying to do something quite simple in theory.

First, I'm using [Vue.js 2](https://github.com/vuejs/vue), [vue-router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router) & [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). I fetch data from a database (with an API).

I'm [fetching it before route enter](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation) of vue-router, to be sure to have my data when my page component is created. Here is my component :

```
<template>
    <section v-html="content"></section>
</template>


<script>

export default {
    name: 'home',
    data() {
      return {
        content: undefined,
      }
    },
    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
      GetData( `${to.params.slug}`, (data) => {
        next(vm => {
          vm.processData(data);
        });
      } );
    },
    methods: {
      processData(data){
        this.content = marked(data.content);
      }
    },
}

</script>
```

`GetData` is a custom function that request data from my API and returns me formatted JSON.

`processData` is a component method that parse some of the JSON to format it in a way that I can easily use it in my template.

Some of my data are user-written markdown content. In `processData`, i'm converting it into HTML with [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked).

Let's admit I have this data coming from my API :

```
datas: { 'content': '# Title⏎Some text⏎![Image title](/some/path/image.jpg)' }
```

In `processData`, it's converting the markdown into HTML and affect it to a component data like this :

```
this.content = marked(data.content);
```

So `this.content` is equal to :

```
<h1>Title</h1><p>Some text</p><img title="Image title" src="/some/path/image.jpg" />
```

I now just have to put in in my component template like this :

Everything is good for now ! My template is filling well.

BUT, here is the problem ; I want to add a custom directive to each of my images coming from the markdown content. Like a lazyload, or a lightbox, or whatever useful directive, even vue native ones.

What I tried is to set a directive when I parse the markdown by editing the data string of each image coming through, but `v-html` is already a directive, so there is no evaluation of this code.

Any idea how to get this ? And think this is just an example but I definitely would like to add any directive on any user async content i'm getting. Maybe I'm doing it wrong from the beginning. I'm clueless.

Thanks.

Comment: You should take a look at the render function: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#ad .

Comment: I can compile it indeed, that's good. But I can't figure how to append inside my dom after.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/